# Symmetrical Mapping Data Structure

Tags: java, mapping, treemap

I'm using a `TreeMap` to store sorted information. Both the keys and the objects indexed by them are of type `String`. But, what I really want is a mapping that's "symmetrical". By this I mean I can `get()` either object (i.e. `String`) from the map by using the other one as a key. I'd still like it to be sorted by one of the objects. Does such a mapping structure exist? FWIW, there are no duplicate pairs in the data.

Comment: Would adding the keys symmetrically to the `TreeMap` be acceptable, e.g. `map.put(a, b); map.put(b, a);` ?

Comment: Interesting. Probably more efficient than using two `TreeMap`s or iterating over the map when doing a look up in the "reverse" direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symmetrical mapping by adding the keys to the `TreeMap` symmetrically:

```
map.put(a, b);
map.put(b, a);
```

This isn't exactly a special data structure, but it sounds like it would meet your requirements.